# qemu adding a non bootable floppy raw format image into an existing virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, floppy

This is the issue: I created a floppy image which I want to add to an existing virtual machine. I added the disk from the virtual machine manager but when I boot the vm I get this error:

Automatically detecting the format is dangerous for raw images, write operations on block 0 will be restricted. Specify the 'raw' format explicitly to remove the restrictions.

I found many threads about how to remove this restriction with a command such as this:
qemu-system-x86_64 -blockdev driver=file,node-name=f0,filename=/path/to/floppy.img -device floppy,drive=f0

I am able to run command just fine, problem is, it is attached to a "new vm" and wants to run as bootable. That is not what I want. I want to simply be able to boot up my existing virtual machine and have the floppy image be mounted in it without restrictions,so it can show up in the desktop or the the file manager.

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a workaround, though not persistent. But at least allows me to r/w to a raw floppy disk. This is how I solve it.
I have aqemu installed to manage the virtual machines. I select the virtual machine (OFF) I need to connect the floppy disk -> Under Media tab -> Select the Add Storage device option -> In the New Storage Device dialog choose File and choose the floppy.img file I want attached, Click the Interface IDE, Index for IDE Floppy giving it a index of 0 or 1, 1 if you already have a 0 index floppy. Click OK. Start the VM. It might give you an error but will allow the VM to start and once in the VM, the device will show up and will be r/w.
I found out that after you shutdown and restart the machine the VM might not start because the storage device is raw format. All you have to do is remove the storage device from the vm, and restart the vm. Should start just fine without the storage. If you want to again work with the floppy image, you might have to repeat the process. I know it is annoying, but since I only use it for a one time use, it is fine with me.

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu and thank you for contributing.  Please take the [tour].